# how to make http get request and hide link to request

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one problem how to make get request. I have [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/5v7ucrcL/):

**HTML**

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" placeholder="text" size="40px">
<br>
<input type="button" id="go" name="go" value="go">
```

**JS**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        url=$("#url").val()
        $.ajax({
            url:"process.php",
            type:"GET",
            data:"url="+url,
            success:function(result){
                $("#go").html(result)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

In process.php I make a link for this form.

```php
<?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $link = file_get_contents("https://parsedurl.com/?url=".$url."");
    $parse = json_decode($link, true);
    $md = $parse['user_id'];
    $nd = $parse['email_id'];
    $pro = file_get_contents("http://domain2.com/complete?id=".$md."_".$nd."");
    if($pro == 0 ){
        echo "success";
    }elseif (!$pro != 0) {
        echo "error";
    }elseif (!$pro) {
        echo "link error";
    }else{
        echo "put a link";
    }
?>
```

I need to make GET request to `http://domain2.com/` not POST but not redirect to this page and get the response in my page.

Comment: what is the error or issue??

Comment: it make post request not GET

Comment: Not sure if you edited your Fiddle after posting the question, but it seems it's performing a **GET** request. Well, at least that happened when I set the correct ID when binding the click event: `$('#go').click( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is what you wanted to achieve but this is how I do PHP requests with AJAX and gather data without refreshing the current page.

I use a switch because I think it's easier to handle the response in that way but you can easily change so it fits you.
The switch will check the response that is echoed in the PHP and then use that in the switch, have the DEFAULT so it throws a general error.

I changed as much of the code so it's adjusted to your code but I might have missed some.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tc8yuy66/

```
//Sends request to process.php
$("#test").click(function() {
//Get data
var data = {};
data.email = $("#email").val();

  //Info for submit
  var options = {};
  options.data = data;
  options.dataType = 'text';
  options.type = 'post';
  options.url = 'process.php';
  options.success = function(response) {
    //Response switch isn't neccesary but I prefer it
    switch (response) {
      case "success":
        //Successful, do something
        break;
      case "error":
        //throw error
        break;
      case "link error":
        //throw error
        break;
      case "put a link":
        //throw error
        break;
      default:
        //throw default error, this is in case something goes really bad
        break;
    }
  };
  //Runs ajax request
  $.ajax(options);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to request and get a response from that domain, or process your data on a file in that domain?

In that first case: use AJAX `$.post` method.

In the second case then you can just set the forms action attribute:
http://www.domain2.com/process.php">

But I don't recommend processing data on another server as that is not efficient nor as secure. You should just process data on your server, however if you are using an API, then you can use the first case.

[W3Schools jQuery.post() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)